# it is ok if the resolver returns more data

Tags: node.js, graphql

according to the scheme should return {x, y}`.

```
function normal() {
  return { x: 1, y: 2 };
}
```

but it returns `{x, y, z}`.

```
function normal() {
  return { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };
}
```

is it normal ? Or it can lead to a problem for example performance

Comment: Follow This => "strict": true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's perfectly ok** and:

- frequently used to pass additional data to nested resolvers accessible by `parent` - 1st resolver arg (`parent.z`);
- extra fields are filtered out before response (query matching).

**Problems?** It depends on the scale of this "overfetching":

- mainly more memory used;
- can prevent separate, additional DB queries (better performance)